# credit debit balance using variable in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Greeting 
I am new with SQL Server i have a table Transaction with  the attribute Debit, Credit and other columns, i want to calculate balance but i cant use CTE Query
expect result should be like ....

**Debit**        **Credit**        **Balance** 
10,000         0              10,000   
0           3,0000            7,000  
5,000        0               12,000

previously i did it  in mysql using variables as below

```
SELECT  A.Debit,A.Credit, @b := @b + A.Debit - A.Credit AS balance
FROM (SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy  
 CROSS JOIN FinTrans A
```

but I am new to MSSQL SERVER How do I do it in MSSQLSERVER
Thanks in Advance

Comment: No id/sequence/timestamp column to include?

Comment: In SQL-SERVER you can use the Window-Functions `OVER()` which could help you

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012, you would use the ANSI standard cumulative sum functions:

```
select ft.*,
       sum(debit - credit) over (order by ??) as balance
from FinTrans ft;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering for your cumulative sum.

In fact, this might typically look like:

```
select ft.*,
       sum(debit - credit) over (partition by <account id column>
                                 order by <ordering column
                                ) as balance
from FinTrans ft;
```

That is, this is how you would do the calculation for different accounts at the same time.

Comment: thnx Mr Gordon Linoff you save my time